# How to embed images directly from a webpage with \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to put four images (a monkey, bird, kitten, and puppy), each from a different website, in my latex code, but I have absolutely no idea what to do. I've checked similar questions on this site, but I'm still confused.

```
http://wikiclipart.com/monkey-clipart-black-and-white_9254/

https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-image-cartoon-bird-black-white-line-retro-style-vector-available-image37023576

http://weheartit.com/entry/63058954

https://freeclipartimage.com/article/top-84-101-dalmations-clip-art
```

For `\includegraphics{...}` I don't even know how to download a picture properly apparently, let alone use this command.

```
\documentclass[28pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{chessfss} %chess figure for HW #2
\usepackage[english]{babel} %table for problem A.43
\usepackage{multirow} %table for problem A.43
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} color certain blocks in a table
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  just to show the margins
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{array}  %BETWEEN TWO 2-DIGIT NUMBERS
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}

\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{case}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}


\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}{11}
\textbf{A child matches the pictures}
\write18{http://wikiclipart.com/monkey-clipart-black-and-white_9254/} %wht does this do?
\includegraphics{} %what is this and how can I use this?
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Save the images to disk and use `\includegraphics` on those four file names.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a good idea. Keep in mind, that the image may no longer be available on the internet at some point in the future or the URL just changed. This could make it difficult to impossible the change your document later. And all solutions I can think of would require downloading the images anyway and they would depend on the OS used.

Comment: At best you will recopy (download) the image every time you build the document.